# php export excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am woking on exporting datas to excel file from mysql.I google some docs and finally I choose the PHPExcel,it works well and I can successfully complete my work.
but when I upload my code to the online server,it display an error which is "XMLWriter is not found",I also google for this and I know it because the installed php isn't compiled with the class "XMLWriter ",but the question is I have no privilege to recompile the php source.
so if there is other open source class that is used to export data to excel file?
I hope I describe my question clearly.

Comment: http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/

Comment: If you don't have XMLWriter enabled, you can still generate xls, csv, html, pdf, etc... just not xml-based formats such as xlsx.... but any library that generates xlsx is certainly also going to need XMLWriter enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can avoid using `PHPExcel`, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/) for a plain and simple solution, it might help.

Since you have no control on your PHP installation, I *strongly* suggest you to abandon `PHPExcel`, as your PHP version does not include the needed libraries for this package and you don't want to go though painful hacks to make it work *somehow*...

Comment: I will try this!thank you!but it rely on the XMLWriter Class?

Comment: Nope, this is the point: it uses only plain PHP to create a standard CSV file that can be digested by Excel.